# D3: The data on the axis not mapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, bar-chart

I have tried to implement a bar chart in D3, but I have a problem with the mapping on my axes. I have a dataset with x and y but it seems that my values are not mapped correctly.

This is the code:

```
var data = [
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 5, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 10},
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 5, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 19},
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 5, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 10},
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 5, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 10},
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 5, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 10},
                                            {x: 2, y:  4},
                                            {x: 3, y:  8},
                                            {x: 8, y: 10},
                                            {x: 24, y:  4},
                                            {x: 15, y:  8},
                                            {x: 18, y: 10}
                                        ];


                                        var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                                            w = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
                                            h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                                        var x = d3.scale.linear()
                                            .range([0, w]);

                                        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                                            .range([h, 0]);

                                        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                            .scale(x)
                                            .orient("bottom");
                                            //.tickFormat(d3.format("%Y/%m"));

                                        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                            .scale(y)
                                            .orient("left");

                                        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
                                            .scaleExtent([1, 1])
                                            .x(x)
                                            .on("zoom", zoomed);

                                        var chart = d3.select("#testChart").append("svg")
                                            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
                                            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                            .append("g")
                                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                                            .call(zoom);

                                        var rect = chart.append("rect")
                                            .attr("width", w)
                                            .attr("height", h)
                                            .style("fill", "none")
                                            .style("pointer-events", "all");

                                        chart.append("g")
                                            .attr("class", "x axis")
                                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                                            .call(xAxis)



                                        chart.append("g")
                                            .attr("class", "y axis")
                                            .call(yAxis);

                                        //data.forEach(function (d) {
                                              //d.date = new Date("20" + d.yy + "/" + d.mm);
                                              // coerce to number
                                                //d.ppm_value = +d.ppm_value;
                                               // d.date = format.parse(d.date);
                                                //console.log(d.ppm_value);
                                               // console.log(d.date);
                                            //});

                                        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                                            console.log("HEelllppp!!!!",d.date);
                                            return d.x;
                                        }));
                                        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                                            return d.y;
                                        })]);

                                        var bars = chart.append("g")
                                            .attr("class", "chartobjects");

                                        bars.selectAll(".rect")
                                            .data(data)
                                            .enter().append("rect")
                                            .attr("class", "rectBar")
                                            .on("click", hello)
                                            .attr('x', function (d) {
                                             console.log("Blaaannaaaaa!!!!!!",d.x);
                                                return x(d.x);
                                            })
                                            .attr("y", function (d) {
                                                return y(d.y);
                                            })
                                            .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.y); })
                                            .attr("width", 45)
                                            .attr("fill", function(d){
                                                 return d.y > 6 ? "blue" : "red"});

                                       function hello(){
                                           alert("Hello world!!")
                                       }

                                        function zoomed() {
                                            var tx = Math.max(0, d3.event.translate[0]);
                                                //ty = Math.min(0, d3.event.translate[1]);
                                            zoom.translate([tx]);
                                            bars.attr("transform", "translate(" + [tx] + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
                                            chart.select(".x.axis")
                                                .call(xAxis);
                                            //chart.select(".y.axis")
                                            //  .call(yAxis);
                                        }
```

Maybe you have some ideas why.  I will also post a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation here has to do more with the dataviz principles than with D3 code.

A bar chart is different from an histogram, and the main difference is this: in a bar chart, each bar represents a **qualitative** variable (or a **categorical** variable). That being said, you shouldn't use a linear scale for your x axis, but an ordinal one instead:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([0, w]);
```

Here is a demo with an ordinal scale:

```js
var data = [{
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 19
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 5,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 10
}, {
    x: 24,
    y: 4
}, {
    x: 15,
    y: 8
}, {
    x: 18,
    y: 10
}];


var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    },
    w = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([0, w], 0.6);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([h, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
//.tickFormat(d3.format("%Y/%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var rect = chart.append("rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");



//data.forEach(function (d) {
//d.date = new Date("20" + d.yy + "/" + d.mm);
// coerce to number
//d.ppm_value = +d.ppm_value;
// d.date = format.parse(d.date);
//console.log(d.ppm_value);
// console.log(d.date);
//});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.x;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.y;
})]);

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
    .call(xAxis)

chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var bars = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "chartobjects");

bars.selectAll(".rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "rectBar")
    .on("click", hello)
    .attr('x', function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return h - y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return d.y > 6 ? "blue" : "red"
    });

function hello() {
    alert("Hello world!!")
}

function zoomed() {
    var tx = Math.max(0, d3.event.translate[0]);
    //ty = Math.min(0, d3.event.translate[1]);
    zoom.translate([tx]);
    bars.attr("transform", "translate(" + [tx] + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    chart.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis);
    //chart.select(".y.axis")
    //  .call(yAxis);
}
```

```css
.axis path,.axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: black;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

But if you want to keep your linear scale and positioning the bars according to the `x` value in the dataset, dont use `map`, which returns an array with all `x` values: simply set the domain to `[minValue, maxValue]`, whatever those values are.

Comment: I did this, but it still does not map my x and y values on the axis. I have value like 0.0,0.2 and those I do not have in my data set.

Comment: You don't have 0.0 or 0.2. Look again at your data array. Besides that, it was just a general explanation, your code - and your data - have some problems that you have to solve.

Comment: I know. I need to map my data array on the axis, but it does not work. I do the mapping like this: x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
             console.log("HEelllppp!!!!",d.x);
                 return d.x;
             }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                 return d.y;
             })]);

Comment: I had some scrolling implemented but now it does not work anymore. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Because I took it off to make the snippet simpler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127806/discussion-between-blaa-and-gerardo-furtado).

Comment: When I put everything back it seems to overlap with some other values on the y axis

Comment: What are you trying to do? A bar chart? A histogram? I believe my answer is clear enough, now it's just a matter of deciding what visualization you want and setting up the code accordingly.

Comment: I want a bar chart with bounded panning and it seemed to work with my initial code, but I clearly have made some mistakes and now it does not work anymore. I don't know why

Comment: I get this error when I implement the panning: d3.v3.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function(…)

Comment: As the panning is another problem, I suggest you post another question, so we avoid answering questions in the comments.

Comment: You were a great help! Thank you very much! I will post another question.